# How do I run Python code entered on a browser on Django views?

Tags: django

I have built a platform on django for running python scripts. The user is able to write their Python script in a text-area and when a button is clicked, the script should run on the back-end. It should also check for test cases from a database (like Hackerrank).

I have tried using the `eval()` function but the problem is that when the user writes `input()` in their code it should take the values from database for input.

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: Please don't use `eval`, it is really ev*i*l: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice It is a very unsafe way to handle a call. A hacker might read out the entire database, or stop your server.

Comment: you'll need to be more specific and show us the code. what values from database? if user inputs a string, how do you know what should be replaced? give a concrete example, show what's in the database, walk us through your problem.

Comment: @jatin can you please show us your code.

Comment: Edited the question + title to fix language and spelling issues.